# Undefined index error in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I use this library : http://www.in-the-attic.co.uk/2010/07/21/mailchimp-api-1-2-library-for-code-igniter/

When I do this :

```
$this->load->library('mcapi');
$this->load->config('mcapi', TRUE);

// get list members
$retval = $this->mcapi->listMembers('0000000', 'subscribed', null, 0, 5000 );

    foreach($retval as $member){
    echo $member['email']." - ".$member['timestamp']."\n";
}
```

I get this Error :

```
A PHP Error was encountered  
Severity: Notice    
Message: Undefined index: email    
Filename: tabs/mailchimp.php    
Line Number: 18
```

But When I print the array with print_r() , it works fine ? :

```
$retval = $this->CI->mcapi->listMembers('0000000', 'subscribed', null, 0, 5000 );
print_r($retval) ;
```

I get the data like this :

```
Array ( [total] => 2 [data] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [email] => email@gmail.com [timestamp] => 2012-01-06 09:29:31 )
```

Any help ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do `<?php foreach($retval['data'] as $member) { } ?>` - the array containing the 'email' key is nested inside the data array.